# write/wall message to users with color

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, write

Is it possible to send messages to other users (i.e. via the `wall` and/or `write` commands), with colors in the message? I have a shutdown script that kicks other users off of a shared file server, and I want to make the message more obvious to them by either making it red, or piping it through [`lolcat`](https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat) and [`cowsay`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay).

I've attempted to paste Bash color codes (i.e. `RED='^[[31m'`), but they get converted to plain printing characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downtime notification isn't entirely a technical problem. If there is a policy of user notification of downtime on this box, do so via agreed-upon channels.

---

Regarding control characters, not with wall or write.  util-linux README indicates this is intentional.

```
Version 1.32b (12-Mar-95):
        Write/wall now strips control chars except BEL (\007). Again after
        suggestion by Rik Faith.
```

Multiple line `wall` usually work, specifically if you use a file argument.

[figlet](http://www.figlet.org/) is another option for your ASCII art.